# Installing CUDA 9.2 with VS 2019

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA 10.1 and 9.2 on my Windows 10 x64 system. (I need both because some software still relies on 9.2 to build and run.) I have Visual Studio 2019 installed. Installing 10.1 (`cuda_10.1.105_418.96_win10.exe`) works well, put when trying to do the base install for 9.2 (`cuda_9.2.148_win10.exe`), it warns me that no suitable VS version was found.

I found that [9.2 only supports up to VS 2017](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/9.2/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html), but is there a way to make it work with VS 2019. I really don't like having more dependencies than I actually need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found that 9.2 only supports up to VS 2017, but is there a way to make it work with VS 2019. I really don't like having more dependencies than I actually need.

CUDA 9.2 is not compatible with any version of Visual Studio 2019.

It appears that the basic purpose of the CUDA 10.1 was to fix an incompatibility with the library headers and CUDA's NVCC compiler.

Microsoft explains the problem in detail:

> The crux of the problem is about two C++ compilers adding modern C++
>   standard features at different paces but having to work with a common
>   set of C++ headers (e.g. STL headers). We heard from many of you that
>   this issue is forcing you to stay behind on older versions of Visual
>   Studio. Thank you for that feedback. Together with NVIDIA, we have a
>   solution in place that enables all Visual Studio 2017 updates and
>   Visual Studio 2019 versions to work with CUDA 10.0+ tools.

I would verify that the software that requires CUDA 9.2 does not actually work with CUDA 10.1 since at first glance it appears that 10.1 supports both Visual Studio 2017 (15.6+) and Visual Studio 2019 and fixes the compatibility first and foremost.

**Basically, there isn't a way around this problem, if there was Nvidia would have released an update for CUDA 9.2.**

Source: [CUDA 10.1 available now, with support for latest Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 versions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cuda-10-1-available-now-with-support-for-latest-microsoft-visual-studio-2019-versions/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have only one of two options; either install Visual Studio 2017 beside Visual Studio 2019, or upgrade the old software that uses CUDA 9.2 to CUDA 10.2.